# I get the error module 'keygen' has no attribute 'keygen

Tags: python, image-processing, encryption, encoding

I have also installed the appropriate libraries but still the error is showing. The code is written below:

```
import keygen as kg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
img = mpimg.imread('Images/111.png')
plt.imshow(img)
#plt.show()
#Now generating the choatic Key
height = img.shape[0]
width = img.shape[1]
key = kg.keygen(0.01,3.951,height*width)
```

I get error at last line.

Comment: You didn't import the keygen module, what is kg supposed to be an alias for?

Comment: @mlb6300 the line `import keygen as kg` was hidden due to wrong code formatting. @RehmanAli the code has to start in the line after ```, not on the same line.

Comment: I have imported keygen. You can see the first line of code. If there is something that Im missing kindly elaborate as I'm unable to understand.

Comment: @jps I have started code from the next line in the compiler. As you saying to import keygen and then in next line import keygen as kg. This is what I understood from the comment.

Comment: @RehmanAli What I'm saying is, that the line `import keygen as kg` was not visible in your question. You formatted the code with ``` and then put line import keygen as kg directly behind it in the same line. But then it is not visible. That's why mlb6300 asked in his comment. Your original question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/364ada43-112b-463e-bc54-2eb5cf6a273b/view-source). I [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/99aa9cca-49aa-4f60-b661-39d7dda80bda/view-source) the formatting problem.

Comment: From what I see the keygen library has no method called keygen, but rather gen_key. 
https://github.com/pmk456/keygen/blob/main/src/keygen/__init__.py

Comment: voting to close because this is a typo.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It doesnot solve the problem but I thanked for the help and suggestions. The error is still there.

Comment: what documentation are you following that leads you to believe that a `keygen()` method exists that takes three arguments? what's the name of the package, is it even a package, where is the "keygen" module's code from?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Im following this tutorial to understand the Image encryption using chaotic system. Here is the link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UwD0KJr7_g&ab_channel=ChaosandCryptography

Answer (score 0):

here `keygen` if a function not a library code for that function.

```
def keygen(x,r,size):
    key = []
    for i in range(size):
        x = r*x*(1-x)
        key.append(int((x*pow(10,16))%256))
    return key
```